# Rails 5 Active record query not showing left_outer_joins attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do a left outer join to get related attributes and then sort by the related attribute.

My problem is the related attribute pfeature_id is not listed in the output.

I can't find any writings on what I may be doing wrong here.

The examples 1 and 2 below, the related `product_features.pfeature_id`  doesn't show in the listing.

In example 3 the raw sql is run within sqlite3 or mysql and pfeature_id is shown.

One of the pages I referred to was: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
1.

albe@vamp398:/srv/test/brails/brail484b51$ dc exec web bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)

irb(main):002:0>  b=Product.left_joins(:product_feature).select("products.id,
 products.name, product_features.pfeature_id").where("products.id>8").take(2)

  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  products.id, products.name, 
product_features.pfeature_id FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_features" ON 
"product_features"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (products.id>8) 
LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 2]]

=> [#<Product id: 9, name: "redKnife">, #<Product id: 10, name: "pf">]
```

```
2.

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_feature
  has_many :pfeature, through: :product_feature
  
  def self.pf
    # raw sql select using ...
    Product.find_by_sql \
    <<-SQL
      SELECT  products.id, products.name, product_features.pfeature_id FROM products LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        product_features ON product_features.product_id = products.id 
    SQL
  end
end

irb(main):005:0> b=Product.pf.last(4)
        
SELECT  products.id, products.name, product_features.pfeature_id FROM products
 LEFT OUTER JOIN product_features ON product_features.product_id = products.id

=> [#<Product id: 8, name: "11">, #<Product id: 9, name: "redKnife">, 
#<Product id: 10, name: "pf">, #<Product id: 10, name: "pf">]
```

```
3.

Run this sql in sqlite3 or MySQL:

SELECT  products.id, "products".name, product_features.pfeature_id FROM
 "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_features" ON 
"product_features"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE (products.id>8) LIMIT 2

    id  name      pfeature_id
    9   redKnife  NULL
    10  pf        8
```

```
Tables:

  create_table "product_features", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "pfeature_id"
    ...
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is if the column in `select` is not one of the attributes of the model on which the `select` is called on then those columns are not displayed. All of these attributes are still contained in the objects within `AR::Relation` and are accessible as any other public instance attributes. Ex:

```
products = Product.left_joins(:product_feature).select("products.id, products.name, product_features.pfeature_id").where("products.id > 8").take(2)
products.first.pfeature_id
```

For verification, just run these two lines in your console. You'll get your desired output. As it is a `LEFT JOIN`, you might get output as `nil` when one `product` has no `product_features`.

If you want to sort your output, then keep in mind your sorting column should contain `NOT NULL` values. Ex:

```
products = Product.left_joins(:product_feature).select("products.id, products.name, product_features.pfeature_id").where("products.id > 8")

# sort with your desired column
sorted_products = products.sort_by(&:name)
# or
sorted_products = products.sort_by(&:pfeature_id) # make sure `pfeatured_id` is not null for any product
```